# Repeating Bash Task using At

Tags: bash, shell

I am running ubuntu 13.10 and want to write a bash script that will execute a given task at non-pre-determined time intervals. My understanding of this is that cronjobs require me to know when the task will be performed again. Thus, I was recommended to use "at."

I'm having a bit of trouble using "at." Based on some experimentation, I've found that

```
echo "hello" | at now + 1 minutes
```

will run in my  terminal (with and without quotes). Running "atq" results in my computer telling me that the command is in the queue. However, I never see the results of the command. I assume that I'm doing something wrong, but the manpages don't seem to be telling me anything useful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `atq` isn't connected to a terminal. It's printing, just not anywhere that you can see it. You can log to a file (`echo hi > log.txt`), force some action, or (maybe) e-mail a message. But like `cron`, you won't see the results immediately on-screen.

Comment: @Jayesh thank you for the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that commands are run without a terminal (output and input is probably redirected to `/dev/null`), your command would also not run since what you're passing to `at` is not `echo hello` but just `hello`. Unless `hello` is really an existing command, it won't run. What you want probably is:

```
echo "echo hello" | at now + 1 minutes
```

If you want to know if your command is really running, try redirecting the output to a file:

```
echo "echo hello > /var/tmp/hello.out" | at now + 1 minutes
```

Check the file later.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'll play with that.